# Dynamically add multiple CKEDitor in IFRAME Yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, yii

I need Multiple CKEditor in IFRAME Yii.

I have followed  the 
[link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Dynamic-insert-field-jquery-create-instance-editor)
its works for Without IFRAME but I have a popup dialog with an IFrame 
Iframe works with Single instance editor but i need it mulipte

Code for Single Instance :

```
   <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'message', array('id'=>'question_editor','maxlength'=>508)); ?>
    <script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'; ?>"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_MA=[ ['Format','Bold','Italic','Underline','-','Superscript','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent'] ,{ name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] },{ name: 'colors', items: [ 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ] },{name: 'insert',items:['Table','Image']},['Templates']];
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'question_editor', {   toolbar:'MA', height:'140px',width: '95%'  }  );
    </script>
```

Please anyone help me to proceed for Multiple CKEditor instance in IFRAME

Answer (score 0):

Create another text area using Yii code or HTML, change the name and id per your naming convention

```
<textarea name="question_editor2" id="question_editor2" rows="10" cols="80">
       This is second editor.
  </textarea>
```

Replace the textarea with CKEDITOR

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'question_editor2' );
</script>
```